# Parametric vs non-parametric time series modeling

Tags: time-series, survival, multilevel-analysis, intervention-analysis, spectral-analysis

Hi I have a large data set of objects, each containing a set of the same attributes. The attributes are measured quantities like height, width, etc. The data is arranged in a time series so that the value for an attribute for an object is indexed by its time. I want to create a multivariate model of the attributes but was not sure if I should look into parametric or non-parametric methods. Most of the attributes are correlated and dependent on one another so when creating a model I need to have variables representing the other attributes in some way. One of my ultimate goals is to perform time series data mining for intervention analysis. Should I be using hierarchical models since I have multiple objects? Can this possibly be a survival model using a time-to-failure distribution? Any suggestions for methods to look at would be helpful. An example of what my data looks like is shown below. Thanks [image]

Comment: There is no information here on what the "attributes" are.

Comment: Statistically, they can each come from different families of distributions.

Comment: Still no information! Do you mean something qualitative, counted, measured?

Comment: Sorry, they are all measure quantities like height, width, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If your objective is Intervention Detection then you definitely want to use parametric methods. When you construct an ARIMA model it is possible to detect pulses , level shifts , seasonal pulses and local time trends using procedures suggested by Tsay and others [as described here](http://www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf).

Take a look at the flow diagram in http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/blog/entry/build-or-make-your-own-arima-forecasting-model to give you some guidance.